# ActiveRecord - "includes" & "where" gettting Nil and Not Nil Statement, with other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null, include, where-clause

### I want to efficiently get the results using '.includes()'.

I need the includes Table to retrieve the records that are NOT nil. I need to keep the **included: true** in the query.

Using postgres.

Role has many tasks.

Tasks belongs to a Role.

#### The following works but gets the wrong records from the Roles table.

```
Task.includes(:role).where(included: true, roles: {doer: nil})
```

The next part is the IDEA of what I want... 
but obviously syntax is wrong in the where clause's "roles" value.

```
Task.includes(:role).where(
    included: true,
    roles: {
        doer != nil    #=> where 'doer' is not 'nil'
    })
```

I'm looking for an efficient query which is why i did the includes.
I don't know how to get this without multiple where queries.

If you understand the question but think it could be asked better to be more clear, let me know.  I couldn't any clues for this answer anywhere unless multiple where statments are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to avoid strings when possible, so I'd use the following:

`Task.includes(:role).where(included: true).where.not(roles: { doer: nil })`

If you have specifically set the `included` column on the `tasks` table to have `NULL FALSE`, you could also condense the `where` calls into a single call, although this will still only launch one query:

`Task.includes(:role).where.not(included: false, roles: { doer: nil })`

Personally, I'd like to see this cleaned-up a bit with some scopes, providing that these calls are commonplace.  Something like:

`scope :with_doer, -> { includes(:role).where.not(roles: { doer: nil }) }`

so the resulting code would be more readable:

`Task.with_doer.where(included: true)`

You could obviously extend this pattern to the `included: true` bit as well.

Note that ActiveRecord queries are built up and then kicked to the database with a "kicker" which Rails kind of sneakily and hackily does through `#inspect` or `#to_a` most of the time.  So, you don't need to worry about needing to condense the `where`calls into a single call.

Comment: Works well. I like the clean up too, but I need to write it like this, right?: `scope :with_doer, -> { includes(:role).where.not(roles: { doer: nil }) }`

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
Task.includes(:roles).where.not('roles.doer' => nil)
```

This is a rails 4-and-up convention, for rails 3 it would be something like:

```
Task.includes(:roles).where("roles.doer IS NOT NULL")
```

And you don't need the included attribute, it can be removed from the model for these purposes.

Since you do seem to need `included` (oops)

```
Task.includes(:roles).where('tasks.included' => true, 'roles.doer' => !nil)
```

Aaah.. how i love postgres..  When you're asking for efficiency, I think this fails, but I'm returning correct results.  If you benchmark the options, this is correct (I think) but  slow.

```
Task.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" ON roles.user_id = user_id').where("tasks.included IS true AND roles.doer IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: That won't work because it looses the "included: true" part of the query.

Comment: I need the 'included: true' attribute because I want to only get the Tasks which the User has set to include, i.e. 'included: true'.

Comment: No error but only returned an empty array. Not sure why but here is a clue, the following two statements, **give the same results** and the only way they differ is in the `!` part of `!=` ... `Role.where.not('doer' => !nil)` **same results as**: `Role.where.not('doer' => nil)` This is 'Role has many Tasks' and 'Task belongs to a Role'. I think this relates to the empty results. When a different answer had me do pure SQL, it said missing a "FROM" clause

Answer (score 0):

Write SQL statements like this?

Task.includes(:role).where("included = 'true' AND roles.doer NOT 'nil'")

Comment: I tried it out and results said there was a Synax error at or near "'nill'"; I tried it with null too. -- I wish I was good enough at pure SQL to just do it simply like that but my skills aren't there yet.

Comment: according to the answer change nil to `null` with slight change i.e `Task.includes(:role).where("included = true AND roles.doer is NOT null")`

Comment: I tried that yesterday (far as I got with SQL and this query)... I just ran your query and got the same error: 'ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "roles"'

Comment: i think you are using `pg` i added thinking of `mysql`. that is why it is wrong. sorry

Comment: You can chain `where`. Try this? `Task.where(included:true).includes(:role).where('roles.doer IS NOT NULL')`